# ElasticSearch comparative range results

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, range-query

Hi I would like to index objects that look like that

```
{
   uuid: "123",
   clauses: [{ order: 1, uuid: "345"},{ order: 2, uuid: "567"},{ order: 3, uuid: "789"}]

}
```

Is there a way to write a query that matches all the objects that contain 
clauses with uuid: "345" and uuid: "789" but order of the second one is at most two bigger than first one?

So the above example would match but the next one wouldn't :

```
 {
   uuid: "999",
   clauses: [{ order: 1, uuid: "345"},{ order: 2, uuid: "567"},{order: 3, uuid: "777"},{ order: 4, uuid: "789"}]

}
```

The reason is that order of "789" clause is 4 which is more than 2 bigger than "345" clause, which has order 1.

Any help is appreciated!
Thanks,
Michail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this involves using a [`script` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html).

The script I'm using is the following:

```
def idxs = []; 
for (int i = 0; i < doc['clauses.uuid'].values.size(); i++) {
    if (matches.contains(doc['clauses.uuid'].values[i])){
        idxs << i
    }
};
def orders = idxs.collect{ doc['clauses.order'].values[it]}; 
return orders[1] - orders[0] <= 2
```

Basically, what I'm doing is first collection all indices of the clauses which contain a `uuid` in the `matches` array (i.e. 345 and 789). 
Then, with the indices I got I gather all `order` values at those indices. And finally, I check that the second `order` minus the first `order` is not bigger than 2.

```
POST your_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "clauses.uuid": "345"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "clauses.uuid": "789"
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": "def idxs = []; for (int i = 0; i < doc['clauses.uuid'].values.size(); i++) {if (matches.contains(doc['clauses.uuid'].values[i])){idxs << i}}; def orders = idxs.collect{doc['clauses.order'].values[it]}; return orders[1] - orders[0] <= 2",
            "params": {
              "matches": [
                "345",
                "789"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

That will return only the first document and not the second.

Comment: Thanks - I will try it! Do you think this could be very cpu intensive ?- I had in mind to actually precalculate the forwardClauses of each clause and then use nested filtering .. I wonder which approach would be faster during retrieval.

Comment: Clearly, whatever you can compute at indexing time, do it, it'll be much faster at query time.